# CSS: Best way to left align a float:right section

Tags: css

I want what in the good old days would be a two-column table layout. It's for http://paulisageek.com/resume and is working perfectly with:

```
.dates {
  float:right;
  width:171px;
}
```

but I'm sure I'll break the sizes on updates (and different fonts, and browsers, and font-sizes, etc).

Is there a way to make the second column autosize without forcing a width (or using javascript)? Will CSS3 have a way?

Comment: Please don't this the wrong way but I'd *really* change the picture you're using.

Comment: :) Its much better with context http://paulisageek.com/paul.jpg but yeah, I totally agree, that is my project for tonight :)

Comment: Oh, and I don't know if if you're one to talk you 'slack jawed yokel'

Comment: To be fair, I don't put my gravatar on my CV. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Give your dates column a min-width and a max-width instead of a fixed width.  This gives you flexibility but ensures your design won't break:

```
.dates {
  float:right;
  min-width:171px;
  max-width:300px;
}
```

Note that min-width and max-width do not include padding, borders, or margins.

Another possibility is make the dates to align right and display inline:

```
.dates p{
  text-align:right;
  display:inline;
}
```

This way you won't need a separate div for the dates.

...Or, if you want to be super-cutting-edge and ensure that your layout breaks in IE, you can use the [new CSS3 columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn/) (not recommended here, but still worth reading)

Answer (score 1):

What you've got here is something that works extraordinarily well and easily with tables. Not only that it's incredibly backwards compatible. In "pure" CSS it's hard. You can make one of the columns variable width but not both. If you really need that, stick with tables (irrespective of what the semantic HTML zealots might say).

Comment: Funny website, but I disagree.  Tables are great for tabular data, not so hot for layouts...

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it's possible. The keyword to search for is liquid columns. For example [this](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/liquid/) deals with whole  layouts but the points are the same.

Comment: That example is a liquid layout but it is liquid in the sense that the whole page can be variable width. The columns are still fixed width (relative to the outer container) so it doesn't really solve the OP's problem.

Comment: doesn't that just change my px to % basically? Still fixed width on something?